# Database scrolling Buttons

Tags: java

I'm working with 2 database scrolling buttons, but when I run the program only one scrolling button is working the other is not reading the codes.

`public void Connect();` is working but when I put the `public void Connect2();` the `connect();` is not working, but the `connect2();` is the one working.

```
public cReport2() {
    initComponents();
    Connect();
    Connect2();    
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your problem. Can you explain it better? Screenshots or more code are welcome.

Comment: There's no such thing as database scrolling buttons: a database has nothing to do with your view components (in this case, a button). It will be better if you describe your functional requirement along with your technical attempt(s) to fulfill it. Also, provide enough info to replicate or at least understand your issue e.g. stacktrace.

Comment: My question is about this: when i click next the textbox will display the next data and when i click back it will display the previous data on the text field; now my problem is the public void Connect() is not working with Public void Connect2()

Comment: We need more code to help you. What's in connect and connect2? What code is invoked when you click your buttons?

Comment: //Code for connect();
  public void Connect(){
        try{
           smt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
          String sql = "Select * from [PMS.Retirement]";
           rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        
    }

Comment: //code for Connect2();
  public void Connect2(){
        try{
           smt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
           String sql = "Select * from [PMS.Termination]";
           rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        
    }

Comment: They the code is working on solo not with together when i put it on the public form

Comment: Here's a link to more understandable for you http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/databases_and_java_forms.html

the code will work only on one scrolling button but i need two